# How to check whether app is compatible in all devices or not?

Tags: android, device, compatibility

I have developed app and tested it in the all the possible devices i have(i.e. on physical devices,genymotion).But i got reviews from client that in some devices it works and in some devices it won't.

I have added the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

So,I want to know that is there any tool/software available online to find out that app(which i have developed) is compatible in this list of devices with respective information.

Please suggest me other ways to get the info for same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this out it may helpful to you: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270#sources

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool which lets you test your app with multiple virtual and real devices. The link is :

https://testobject.com

Comment: thanks for your valuable response.In above link,we need to select the device and then run the app manually to check whether it is feasible or not.My target is to achieve it automatically by uploading only APK to know that on how many devices my app is compatible or not.Please guide me if i miss anything from your answer.

Comment: You can also use Google Firebase Test lab which is not free.

Comment: @AndroidLearner as Mohsen said you can use Google FireBase Lab which is not free. normally these kinds of services are not free. btw i havent worked alot with testObject myself just a little bit manual testing as you said, but it may have automatic test that i may now know.